# Does the SVN server version affect what version of AnkhSVN or TortoiseSVN I can install?

Tags: svn, tortoise-svn, ankhsvn

Our SVN server version is 1.6.11.  I am setting up a new machine and am wondering if that version affects what versions of AnkhSVN and TortoiseSVN I need to install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"No, it doesn't" in common

**Slightly deeply**

Higher versions of SVN-clients are backward-compatible with **all** relesed versions. Older versions just can't handle later improvements

**Long, nervous and almost obscenely**

1.6 is old, outdated and not maintained version of SVN. Only dumb, lazy and indifferent marmoset (not Admin per se) leave it on server for mission-critical tasks **now**: while most of more recent enhancements are client-side, decent client-server pair (1.8+) offer a lot of usefulness under the hood (read [1.8 changelog](https://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#new-feature-compatibility-table) and [1.9 changelog](https://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.9.html#new-feature-compatibility-table) at least in "New Feature Compatibility Table" parts)

Comment: Yeah, while waiting for an answer, I went ahead and just installed the latest Ankh and Tortoise and everything is working fine.